# How to make palceholder to move to right of options after values got selected in react select package?

Tags: reactjs

I am using 'react-select' package to make a multi select dropdown and added props according to my requirement. But one thing i want more is: I make to make placeholder to move to right of options after values from dropdown got selected.

[image]

Like in image one option is selcted and placeholder in still showing. I want something like this that when I select values placeholder should shifts to right of options.This is how I am using.

````
<Select
            placeholder='Type Team Name...'
            value={getOptions(value)}
            options={getOptions(data)}
            onChange={(data) => setValue(data || [])}
            styles={selectStyles}
            isMulti
            isClearable
            isSearchable
        />
    ```
````

Comment: do you want the placeholder to stick in its place or move to right of options

Comment: move to right of options when they are selected.

Comment: i am finding it difficult to analyse can you recreate this in an online ide like codesandbox and drop me the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-black-jfpor?file=/example.js
I have edited this example I found somewhere.Placeholder disappers when values got selected but I want that placeholder to shift to right of options selected.

Comment: i got the solution and have shared the working code

Comment: Did my solution work for you @mahi  and sorry for deleting that comment I did that by mistake

Comment: @Gayatri Dipali I tried your previous code but that didn't worked for me beacuse the id was changing everytime I select a new option.Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

**The main Javascript file :**

```
import React from "react";
import "./example.css"

import Select from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./data";
setTimeout(async ()=>{
    const reqinput= await document.getElementById("react-select-2-input");
    if(reqinput){
        reqinput.placeholder = "slect colors....";
        reqinput.style.width="550px"
    }else{
        console.log("thu")
    }
},200)

const Example=()=>{
    return(
        <Select
        defaultValue=""
        placeholder="select colors..."
        isMulti
        name="colors"
        options={colourOptions}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
      />
    )
}

export default Example
```

**example.css file:**

```
.css-1wa3eu0-placeholder{
    display: none;
}
```

**I added the css** because when the input was cleared the unwanted `div` was reappearing, hence i had to hide the `div` through css

This is the working i tested it out on my local system.

**If it doesnt** work please don't freak out it is only **because of change in class names and id's** just inspect them and **replace the classes** and id's if required as i have done it with reference to your codesandbox example

**EDIT :**

**The result** of the above mentioned code is:

[image: result]

Comment: How is this answering the question? It just awkwardly hides the placeholder (once) after 200ms. Also it completely works outside of react, which makes it impossible to reuse.

Comment: i dont know why you are telling this but it just works fine for me in my local system

Comment: What is that "it" that is supposed to work? How is the placeholder still visible after adding a value?

Comment: i have edited my answer and added the effect that is supposed to be achieved

Comment: @Yoshi the placeholder which i am asigning to input through js is the only actual placeholder but the other which was present by default (now is not visible) is not not a placeholder but just a div

Comment: I do understand what your're doing. I just think it's no way one should use when using react. Your'e basically *dom hacking* an implementation detail of a third party library. If ever that library changes it's way of rendering the select, it stops working. Also, given as is, it's not reusable. If I were to render `<Example/>` twice it fails. Then the whole async/await parts with `setTimeout` make no sense at all. Sorry if that sounds harsh, but I don't think this is a good answer to the question.

Comment: **yeah i do agree with you**  that this was not the best way of doing it in react but when you want to customise something in a package this is the way i do it if its not possible to do it directly, **if you have any solution of doing it in the react way, please post it as it would help me and @mahi to minimise our code**

Comment: @Yoshi I did try it without adding `setTimeout` but it errors out saying `cannot set placeholder of undefined`  but when i add the `setTimeout` it does not freak out anymore can you explain why?

Comment: Given the implementation of the react-select Select component, I don't think there's a reasonable way to make this work. It's simply a missing feature of the component. Though wrapping it and reacting to values changes might be a starting point. Regarding your `setTimeout` question. In your code the timeout ensures that react had time to render the element before you try to access it via the dom api.

Comment: @Yohi you are right there is no need of async-await after putting an `setTimeout`, because **now its working for me without async-await**